# Co-admin or partial access in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to allow an additional user access the AWS account without giving them my own credentials? Like co-admin, or Active Directory access in Azure.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/iam/

Comment: @VadimBerman because if you google your own question title the answer is within the top 5 results.

Comment: I didn't dv, but hover over the arrow: lack of research is one of the prescribed reasons for downvoting, and I'd agree with that vote.

Comment: Sorry, @thexacre. I googled it, of course, but somehow dismissed the FAQ link. Would you like me to delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iam and single-sign on using Active Directory.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enable-single-sign-on-to-the-aws-console-shibboleth/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enable-single-sign-on-to-the-aws-management-console/

Comment: Thanks, but I can't upvote, because some kind of purist downvoted me.